# Finding Spaces, Newlines and Tabs with charAt()

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to check if there is a space, a newline or a tab at the current character location. Spaces work but tabs and newlines dont. Go figure, I'm using escapes for those, and just a regular space for a space... What's the correct way to find these at a location?

```
if(String.valueOf(txt.charAt(strt)).equals(" ") || 
                    txt.charAt(strt) == '\r' ||
                    txt.charAt(strt) == '\n' || 
                    txt.charAt(strt) == '\t') {
    //do stuff
                    }
```

Comment: What is `txt`? and if it's a `String` ... why are you using `String.valueOf()` ?

Comment: Brian: I suspect because without it equals complained about incompatible types (and `' '` was harder to type?)

Comment: Ok, it's working working correctly. I have a bug elsewhere in my code that isnt working correctly. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me:

```
  char c = txt.charAt(strt);
  if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == '\r')
    System.out.println("Found one at " + strt);
```

Yours works too, although it's a bit harder to follow. Why it doesn't work for you I don't know - maybe the string is badly formed? Are you sure you actually have tabs and stuff in it?

Comment: Changed to this method of comparing to save on cost.

Answer (score 1):

It should work just fine, check your input string. Also, the space can be checked by comparing a blank space character. Creating a new String object just for comparison is costly.

Comment: ... as is extracting each char four times.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs for `Editable` in android, it returns a `char`. Therefore ...

```
if (txt.charAt(strt) == ' ' || 
    txt.charAt(strt) == '\r' ||
    txt.charAt(strt) == '\n' || 
    txt.charAt(strt) == '\t') 
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Will produce the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

This regex [\s] will do the work. It matches the whitespace, Equivalent to [\t\n\r\f].